# Changing Class-set Enum to Non Class-set Enum

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have the error:

```
error: cannot convert 'AudioEngine::input' from type 'mad_flow (AudioEngine::)(void*, mad_stream*)' to type 'mad_flow (*)(void*, mad_stream*)'
```

I have the enum,

```
enum mad_flow AudioEngine::input(void *data, mad_stream *stream)
{
    etc...
}
```

And an external library is calling it,

```
mad_decoder_init(&decoder, &player,
                 input, decode_header, decode_filter, process_output,
                 decode_error, 0 /* message */);
```

The input from that is needed in the external class, but I want to keep my engine class based. How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you actually asking "how do I call a member function from C?"?

Comment: Possibly. I don't really know.

Comment: Hmm, this is going to be hard to answer if you don't really know what you're asking ;)  Can you provide some context (e.g. some surrounding code)?

Comment: The madSdecoder_init is from the libmad, and it pretty much wants the enum in its own way- i.e.enum mad_flow input(void *data, mad_stream* stream). However, the enum uses variables in my class, so I need it wrapped in the class.

Comment: Ok, a brief look at the [documentation](http://m.baert.free.fr/contrib/docs/libmad/doxy/html/decoder_8c.html#e60a642e14509b60f3f7e71d7c38f2ec) reveals that `mad_decoder_init` is expecting a *callback* (i.e. a function pointer), not an *enum*.

Comment: http://m.baert.free.fr/contrib/docs/libmad/doxy/html/callbacks_8h.html#8eee2a05b462fb920e3306b7f44b7fc2 - I need to use that both in the class, and without the AudioEngine:: thing. Is there either a way that I can convert it, or access the class variables when it doesn't have the AudioEngine::?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your function a static member. Your class declaration looks like this:

```
class AudioEngine
{
    ...    
    enum mad_flow input(void *data, mad_stream *stream);
    ...
};
```

You should make it like so:

```
class AudioEngine
{
    ...    
    static enum mad_flow input(void *data, mad_stream *stream);
    ...
};

mad_decoder_init(...
                 &AudioEngine::input,
                 ...);
```

Actually, in order to make a C++ function callable from C, one should declare it outside of a class, and prepend `extern "C"` to it:

```
class AudioEngine
{
    ...    
    static enum mad_flow input(void *data, mad_stream *stream);
    ...
};

extern "C" enum mad_flow AudioEngine_input_callback(void *data, mad_stream *stream)
{
    return AudioEngine::input(data, stream);
}

mad_decoder_init(...
                 AudioEngine_input_callback,
                 ...);
```

However, in practice, the first solution (just prepending `static` to the member function's declaration) will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm seeing if I can tinker the QAudioDecoder now, but should that fail, I'm sure this will definitely help. Either way, I finally get what the extern "C" means now!